# convert field of varbinary datatype before returning function as a dataset

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, web-services

I Am using VS2008 ASP Web forms
Objective is to make images in records available to end user via web services, with HTTPhandler for streaming

How may i convert 'product_image_bytes' (varbinary) into bytes before returning the function as a dataset?

```
sql.AppendLine("SELECT product_category_name, product_image_bytes ... FROM Product WHERE product_status =" & "'sent'")
Try
    conn.Open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql.ToString, conn)
    da.Fill(itemData)
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snipet of ASP.Net code that would take an HTTP request with an id param and stream back a binary from a SQLServer table.  Is that what you were going for?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ImageID"] != null)
    {
        string strQuery = "select Name, ContentType, Data from" +
            " tblFiles where id=@id";
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value
            = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ImageID"]);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch
        {
            dt = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        if (dt != null)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
                + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ty :) but what i need was product_image_bytes to be returned as bytes within the resultset?

Comment: @brainsfrying - In my example I'm reading in a column called Data that is a varbinary() field in SqlServer.  Then I set a Byte[] array var called bytes from the DataTable and finally use the Response.BinaryWrite() method to return that in an HTTP response. I know I'm in C# and you're in VB.Net but isn't this your goal?